# Why did Stack Overflow try to perform a forbidden TCP connection to my IP address?

Tags: discussion

I tuned my router's [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) configuration. And just for fun, I tried monitoring the blacklisted IP addresses (through the recent module).

And it turns out that one of the blacklisted IP addresses belongs to Stack Overflow...

```
root@cortex:/# cat /proc/net/xt_recent/TCP_BLACKLIST
src=128.61.240.66 ttl: 240 last_seen: 8265287 oldest_pkt: 1 8265287
src=123.249.24.160 ttl: 110 last_seen: 8171243 oldest_pkt: 1 8171243
src=61.183.128.6 ttl: 239 last_seen: 8183398 oldest_pkt: 1 8183398
src=188.138.9.50 ttl: 111 last_seen: 8165841 oldest_pkt: 1 8165841
src=60.173.10.166 ttl: 105 last_seen: 8162063 oldest_pkt: 1 8162063
src=71.6.165.200 ttl: 109 last_seen: 8226537 oldest_pkt: 2 8063636, 8226537
src=198.252.206.149 ttl: 48 last_seen: 8130805 oldest_pkt: 17 8076919, 8077127, 8077543, 8078375, 8078890, 8080039, 8082509, 8083367, 8087288, 8090024, 8099288, 8102023, 8123816, 8125694, 8126147, 8128439, 8130805, 8074692, 8076764, 8076816
src=200.252.182.2 ttl: 48 last_seen: 8131508 oldest_pkt: 1 8131508
src=178.205.188.110 ttl: 46 last_seen: 8135176 oldest_pkt: 5 8075125, 8075425, 8123463, 8127368, 8135176
src=61.160.213.54 ttl: 109 last_seen: 8262006 oldest_pkt: 3 8076255, 8122820, 8262006

root@cortex:~# nslookup 198.252.206.149
Server:    192.168.1.1
Address 1: 192.168.1.1 cortex

Name:      198.252.206.149
Address 1: 198.252.206.149 stackoverflow.com
```

Why is this happening? What port is Stack Overflow trying to access? And why?

Here is how I blacklist; it's a quite simple rule. All the blacklisting is done after checking for ESTABLISHED/RELATED connections (-I INPUT/FORWARD 2):

```
# Main black list chain
iptables -N IN_BlackList

# Mark all packets coming through BlackList as (TCP/UDP/OTHER)_BLACKLIST
iptables -A IN_BlackList -m recent --set --name BLACKLIST --rsource
iptables -A IN_BlackList -p tcp -m recent --set --name TCP_BLACKLIST   --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst
iptables -A IN_BlackList -p udp -m recent --set --name UDP_BLACKLIST   --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -A IN_BlackList        -m recent --set --name OTHER_BLACKLIST --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# Reject all TCP packets from the TCP_BLACKLIST
iptables -I INPUT 2   -p tcp -m recent --name TCP_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -p tcp -m recent --name TCP_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst

# Reject all UDP packets from the UDP_BLACKLIST
iptables -I INPUT 3   -p udp -m recent --name UDP_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -I FORWARD 3 -p udp -m recent --name UDP_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# Reject all remaining packets from the OTHER_BLACKLIST
iptables -I INPUT 4   -m recent --name OTHER_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
iptables -I FORWARD 4 -m recent --name OTHER_BLACKLIST --rsource --update --seconds 3600 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# If did not match anything, mark as blacklisted
iptables -D INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -j IN_BlackList

#Drop invalid packets
iptables -I INPUT 2   -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

nmaping the address gives this:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-03 21:45 CET
Nmap scan report for stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.149)
Host is up (0.100s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE   VERSION
80/tcp  open  http
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 502)
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
443/tcp open  ssl/https
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 502)
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/organizationName=Stack Exchange, Inc./stateOrProvinceName=NY/countryName=US
| Not valid before: 2013-06-18T23:00:00+00:00
|_Not valid after:  2016-06-23T11:00:00+00:00
|_ssl-date: 2015-03-03T20:46:20+00:00; 0s from local time.
| tls-nextprotoneg:
|_  http/1.1
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X|3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 2.6.32 - 3.10
Network Distance: 16 hops
```

I can clearly see this in the SSL certificate:

> commonName=qa.sockets.stackexchange.com

Is that some websocket trying to access my IP address?
I thought they only relied on port 80/443....

[EDIT]
reproduced today, and the log gives:

> TCPREJECT IN=vlan2 OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=198.252.206.149 DST=X.X.X.X LEN=110 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=35030 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=60959 SEQ=3005649284 ACK=2231676172 WINDOW=39 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 OPT (0101080AB943E964001381F7)

No doubt it gets banned because of the weird DPT=60959 port...
Still need to figure out what is causing this DPT=60959

Comment: I'm asking here because I'm confident regarding my iptable rule, but I don't know what Stack Overflow is trying to do...

Comment: What port numbers are you getting from StackOverflow in your logs? That'll give a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: I don't know :(  I didn't enable logging... but for sure it was a TCP packet, not UDP. the ip is part of the TCP_BLACKLIST list, which is only filled by TCP packets

Comment: and why would Stack Overflow try accessing ports outside an already estabished connection ?

Comment: Possibly related: [stackexchange.com is sending me unsolicited packets (and consequently gets blocked by firewall)](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/stackexchange-com-is-sending-me-unsolicited-packets-and-consequently-gets-block)

Comment: I've seen firewalls lose track of TCP/IP sessions (time them out) and treat subsequent packets as unsolicited. You'd see a log match for _source_ port 80, destination port >1024.

Comment: ok, I guess I need to read about this timeout issue and about websockets... I guess I should also enable logging...

Comment: @hichris123: not just 'possibly'.

Comment: I'm guessing that those are websockets that SO is trying to establish with your machine, so that real-time notifications and such work.

Comment: Another possibility is that stackoverflow is actively probing whether an IP is an open proxy, to thwart spammers; although that seems unlikely

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/stackexchange-com-is-sending-me-unsolicited-packets-and-consequently-gets-block

Comment: @Undo With websocket connections the client initiates the connection.

Answer (score 6):

Just copying and pasting the response from an [identical issue at unix.se](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/stackexchange-com-is-sending-me-unsolicited-packets-and-consequently-gets-block):

https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3283/49422:

> ***Shog9** answers:*
>
> Gonna throw out a wild guess: your filter sees web socket traffic as "unsolicited".
>
> We use websockets to provide real-time updates for various events happening on the site. If you're blocking HTTP responses that fall outside of a strict window, this will probably break.
>
> If that doesn't jibe with what you're seeing, you'll have to post more info.
>
> ***Martin Vegter** (OP) comments:*
>
> thanks, but this is standard iptables rule: `--ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED.` I have no idea about the inner workings of this module, but I would expect it inspects packets and decides whether it is related to existing session or not. Apparently, some packets fail this test.
>
> ***Caleb** responds:*
>
> @MartinVegter `iptables --ctstate` (and other forms of state tracking) are not always up to date with the way the web works. In this case you are the one blocking websocket traffic. You need to allow this traffic and leave it up to your browser to authenticate it with existing sessions (or reject it). It is not the job of a firewall to implement and be able to verify all communication protocols, only to decide which protocols you want to use. Stop blocking the protocol and the standard systems that use websockets will start working again, simple as that.

https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3297/49422:

> ***Mark** answers*:
>
> Your "anti-portscan" rules do not play well with long-lasting, low-traffic connections. The StackExchange sites use such connections in the form of websockets to update the status bar. If a status bar update arrives after the connection-tracking timeout has expired, the server that sent the update will be blocked for five minutes.
>
> ...

Note that port 443 (remote port in OP logs) is HTTPS, lending evidence to mistracked websockets traffic, the local port being whatever random port was chosen on the client side (60959 is in the dynamic/private port range used for this purpose).